# Looping React Axios result

Tags: reactjs, axios

my purpose is to printout http request´s result set.
I don´t know what is the working way to loop with this result.

```
 const result = await axios.get("http...");
[
  {
    "A": "SSS NNN",
    "B": "TEXT SSSS",
  },
  {
    "A": "text ttttt",
    "B": "text ttttt",
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
return <>
{
  result.map((r, id) => {
     return <div key={id}>{r.A} {r.B}</div>
  }) 
}
</>
```

Here we capture id because react needs a key prop for every child item to keep track of them internally.

Answer (score 0):

`Axios` returns an object with multiple nested objects but the result of the `api` is stored in the `data` object.

So if you want to access the data object from `axios` there are two ways.

1.) Accessing through `result` object

```
const result = await axios.get("http...")

result.data.map((res, id) => {
  return <div key={id}>{res.A} {res.B}</div>
})
```

2.) You can destructure the `data` object from `api request`

```
const { data } = await axios.get("http...")

data.map((res, id) => {
  return <div key={id}>{res.A} {res.B}</div>
})
```

Comment: Thank you, I have been with other projects, I hope that I can check this soon